# What is the best way to return single object instead of array from jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery

Newb question:

jQuery('.foo')[0] does the job most of the time.
jQuery('.foo:first')[0] is slightly more explicit and performant.
But this isn't nice when array is empty, so check is necessary.

But is there a better way than to use array indexer? i.e. return is a single object or null if not found.

I know it's by design an array is always returned as jQuery's power lies in the "set" operations. But sometimes a more concise syntax does help readability and avoid bugs.

Comment: This came up a few days ago...

Comment: when the array is empty, [0] will return 'undefined' .. is it important that you get 'null' instead ??

Comment: BTW undefined == null (altho undefined !== null)

Comment: It does save me a length check, but I'm trying to avoid putting [0] everywhere.

Comment: Oh, and doesn't [0] break closure as well since it's not a jQuery object necessarily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made you this plugin, hope it's useful:

```
//return single DOM element or null
jQuery.fn.getFirst = function() {
    var ele = jQuery(this).filter(':first')[0];
    if(ele !== undefined) {
        return ele;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Simple test case:

```
<input name="foo" value="hooohooo" class="test"/>
<input name="bar" value="heeeeheeee" class="test"/>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    alert(jQuery('.test').getFirst()); //alerts [object HTMLInputElement]
    alert(jQuery('.nonExistent').getFirst()); //alerts 'null'
});
```

I don't know if `getFirst` is the best name for it, any suggestions? I've also thought `single` and `first` but can't seem to make up my mind.

Comment: +1, nice. Perhaps 'firstResult'? (Though 'getFirst' seems plenty descriptive.)

Comment: I like this one.  I think "first" is a fitting name. Single may imply that there should ONLY be single element in the result, as in .Net Single() extension method.

Comment: I'm surprised that jquery didn't have this as native API since it is so frequently used. It has so many other nice syntactical sugars that made javascript pleasant...

Answer (score 1):

If I the selector is not guaranteed to return at least one element, I tend to iterate the collection with [`each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each).

```
jQuery('.foo').each(function() {
    this;
});
```

I even do this if I am qualifying the selector with something like `:first`.

```
jQuery('.foo:first').each(function() {
    this;
});
```

*Edit: I see other answers implementing a "getFirst" method. Although I fail to see its usefulness, here is my take on it. It has the same functionality, but I think `one` is a more fitting name - avoiding confusion with the `:first` selector. I would be interested to see a use case for this.*

```
/**
 * Return the first item of the collection, or
 * null if the collection is empty.
 */
jQuery.fn.one = function() {
    return this[0] || null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need an extension for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.fn.getFirst = function () {
        if( this.length == 0 )
            return null;
        else
            return this.get(0);
        }

    var ret = 0;
    ret = $(".foo").getFirst();

    if( ret )
        $(ret).text( "Tight!" );
```

There you go, no more array subscripting!